# Use image attributes with plantuml and github_markdown

Tags: markdown, pandoc, plantuml

Is there a way to use [link_attributes](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-link_attributes) and filters with `markdown_github`?

Consider the following minimal example:

````
```{ .plantuml height=0.2cm}
Alice -> Bob: Authentication Request
Bob --> Alice: Authentication Response
```
````

When i run that with the [pandoc-plantuml](https://github.com/timofurrer/pandoc-plantuml-filter) it works as expected.

```
pandoc demo.md --filter pandoc-plantuml -o demo.tex
```

And produces an output like this:

```
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.2cm]{plantuml-images/ce4ad67a96c31b33df8381cc8bb0730a201226b2.png}
```

When I used it with `-f markdown_github`

```
pandoc demo.md --filter pandoc-plantuml -o demo.tex -f markdown_github
```

It produces output like this

```
\texttt{\{\ .plantuml\ height=0.2cm\ \}\ Alice\ -\textgreater{}\ Bob:\ Authentication\ Request\ Bob\ -\/-\textgreater{}\ Alice:\ Authentication\ Response}
```

I tested all the different [Markdown variants](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#markdown-variants) and only commonmark_x seems to work.
I tried to compare the options from commonmark_x and markdown_github and match them with no success.
The full set im using right now for different reasons is:

```
-f markdown_github+yaml_metadata_block+raw_tex+link_attributes+header_attributes
```